# Execute INSERT INTO in PLPGSQL using variables as values

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create function, which adds a record with given variables as values. My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADD_FILM(id INTEGER, t VARCHAR, y INTEGER, p REAL) RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
DECLARE
    query VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    query = 'insert into films (id_film, title, year_production, price) values ('||id||','||t||','||y||','||p||')';
    EXECUTE query;
RETURN 'OK';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Incorrect ID, next available ID set';
    RETURN 0;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
SELECT ADD_FILM(1,'aaa','2020','10');
```

Following function execution ends with error. What's wrong with syntax?

> ERROR:  column "aaa" does not exist

Comment: I don't know for sure how Postgres reacts on wrong arguments in function, but you try to put '2020' **string** as `y INTEGER` argument, and '10' **string** as `p REAL`. And then you insert `id, t, y, p` as **strings** (because `'||id||'` syntax tells to make a string value) in a table, which presumably has numeric types for columns `id_film`, `year_production` and `price`

Comment: Oh, and you probably won't be allowed to use a single quote `'` both on the ends of the  `query` value and inside the query string

Comment: Looks like I took too complicated way and there was much simpler option :D 
But thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather do like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADD_FILM(id INTEGER, t VARCHAR, y INTEGER, p REAL) RETURNS 
VARCHAR AS $$
BEGIN
    insert into films (id_film, title, year_production, price) values (id,t,y,p);
RETURN 'OK';
....
....
```

See this link: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-create-procedure/

And call it:

```
CALL ADD_FILM(1,'aaa','2020','10');
```

Comment: I heard on the lecture about EXECUTE, so thought I should use that, but looks like that wasn't necessary :D
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution with EXECUTE:

```
create table films
(
 id_film int,
 title varchar,
 year_production int,
 price real 
);
CREATE TABLE
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADD_FILM(id INTEGER, t VARCHAR, y INTEGER, p REAL) RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
DECLARE
    query VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    query = 'insert into films (id_film, title, year_production, price) values ($1,$2,$3,$4)';
    EXECUTE query USING id, t, y, p; 
RETURN 'OK';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Incorrect ID, next available ID set';
    RETURN 0;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
CREATE FUNCTION
SELECT ADD_FILM(1,'aaa','2020','10');
 add_film 
----------
 OK
(1 row)

select * from films;
 id_film | title | year_production | price 
---------+-------+-----------------+-------
       1 | aaa   |            2020 |    10
(1 row)
```